# FutureWarning: Method .ptp

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I want to know which line or method caused the Future Warning!

```py
predictors = weekly.columns[1:7] # the lags and volume
X = sm.add_constant(weekly[predictors]) # sm: statsmodels
y = np.array([1 if el=='Up' else 0 for el in weekly.Direction.values])
logit = sm.Logit(y,X)
results=logit.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2389: FutureWarning: Method .ptp is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use numpy.ptp instead.
>     return ptp(axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)

Comment: FYI: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ptp.html

Answer (score 9):

`weekly[predictors]` will return a Series representation of the `weekly[[predictors]]` DataFrame. Since the warning tells to use `numpy.ptp`, then by adding the attribute `values` to `weekly[predictors]` will make the warning disappeared, i.e.

```
X = sm.add_constant(weekly[predictors].values)
```

or you can use the method `to_numpy()`:

```
X = sm.add_constant(weekly[predictors].to_numpy())
```

It will convert the `weekly[predictors]` Series to a NumPy array.

Comment: Unfortunately this method will return a numpy array, not a dataframe, which is annoying because you lose information like the column names and whatnot.

Comment: ```X = weekly[predictors]```
```X['const'] = 1```
These will give headers as well.

Comment: Thanks @user3476359, easiest solution. If one cares about preserving also the column order: sm.add_constant adds the const as the first column, and X.insert(0,'const',1) does the same.

Answer (score 2):

The line which generate this warning is this:

```
X = sm.add_constant(weekly[predictors]) # sm: statsmodels
```

Unfortunately i have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The line that causes the warning is:

```
X = sm.add_constant(weekly[predictors]) # sm: statsmodels
```

This is a utility from statsmodels that adds a column called `const` to the data frame with all `1`.

Since it doesn't work anymore (uses a deprecated function), you can use a different method. I prefer pandas' built-in `assign` method:

```
X = weekly[predictors].assign(const=1)
```

Or even, call it `Intercept` because that's what that constant is for, and to be consistent with the [formula api](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/example_formulas.html) in statsmodels.

```
X = weekly[predictors].assign(Intercept=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve a dataframe instead of returning a numpy array:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(sm.add_constant(weekly[predictors].values, has_constant='add'), columns = ['const'] + weekly[predictors].columns.tolist())
```

Also, your y is already a numpy array, but if y also happens to be a pandas series you might need to call y.reset_index() because once you turn X into a numpy array you lose whatever indices you had.